Wrong quoting of -isystem flags in eglot-events-buffer
I'm investigating why I have so many missing symbols when using eglot. E.g. none of my Qt symbols are recognized. I even tried adding the qt directories explicitly by a .clangd file:
CompileFlags:
     CompilationDatabase: /home/dov/hello-qt/compile_commands.json
     Add: [-isystem /usr/include/qt6, -isystem /usr/include/qt6/QtGui, -isystem /usr/include/qt6/QtCore, -isystem /usr/include/qt6/QtWidgets]


However, when inspecting the output of eglot-events-buffer I found the following line:
[stderr] /usr/bin/clang "-isystem /usr/include/qt6" "-isystem /usr/include/qt6/QtGui" ...


Trying to run this line manually, indeed fails to find, e.g. <QWindow>. The reason is that quotes are in the "wrong" place!
The correct place should be: /usr/bin/clang "-isystem" "/usr/include/qt6" ..., where each argument is quoted separately.. When running an external command the arguments are given in an array, and the erroneous quoting give unrecognized arguments.
Meanwhile I'm easily able to workaround this by using -Ifoo instead of -isystem foo in .clangd, but I'd like to fix this properly.
So who is to blame? clangd? Or eglot? Or am I doing something wrong?
Here are my versions:
$ clang --version
clang version 18.1.8 (Fedora 18.1.8-1.fc40)

Eglot: ;; Version: 1.12.29

" The reason is that quotes are in the "wrong" place!" - what is the "right" place? I don't see anything wrong with the placement of the quotes in the command. What is the ... ellipsis in the command line hiding?

Sorry, I should be clearer. The correct place should be: /usr/bin/clang "-isystem" "/usr/include/qt6" ..., where each argument is quoted separately.. When running an external command the arguments are given in an array, and the erroneous quoting give unrecognized arguments.

You should add that to the question so that it stands complete on its own.

Try an alternative as described on this page.

By default clang does not read automatically the file .clangd - this
is done by passing the argument --enable-config to clangd command.
You may have also a path problem, I do not know where is installed your
package, but you can get rid of this problem by moving such information to
CMakeLists.txt file, as it is shown in documentation. You will need two
paths, one for included headers and another for libraries.
You may need the package exec-path-from-shell to solve these problems.
Also, clang need some additonal arguments as described in this answer to work.
